# Switching scheme for vector controlled pmac drive

Tags: power

I have 28  pmac motors (3-ph, 230 volt of 0.5 kw, 1.05kw an 1.21kw) in motor control center. Please suggest a time staggered switching scheme in order to avoid tripping due to voltage sag, swell , flicker etc

Comment: Can you provide some more information about those motors, what you want to achieve and how you are going to control all those motors

Comment: I think that if you have 28 servo drives that run on 230 volt 3-phase power then you're probably asking for help in the wrong place. No offense intended for anyone here, but this is an internet answer site. While some people (myself included) are engineers by profession, this site is populated from degreed engineers to grade school students and everyone in between, and everyone is free to post an answer. *You should contact a licensed professional engineer for help designing your motor control center.* The internet is great for a lot of things, but industrial controls is not one of them.

Comment: @ ToboiasK: Motor rating is 2500 rpm , rated torque is 1.93 Nm and 0.5 kw. They are vector controlled by asic. I want to implement staggered time switching for these 28 motors. If you can provide some information regarding staggered switching of multiple motors it would be great help.